# Scripting with multiple sections but different result

Tags: applescript

trying to set up a script where a user can select multiple answers.

so prompt asks for example favorite colors and they choose from list "black, white, red, orange, blue".

the user selects white and blue, white equals 101 and blue equals 208
so the result would be 101 instead of white and 208 instead of blue

Comment: Are you wanting to use the selections from one list to get the matching items in another?

Answer (score 1):

You want a `select` statement.

Refer to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/select-loop.htm for how to construct one.  An example from that page...

```
#!/bin/ksh

select DRINK in tea cofee water juice appe all none
do
   case $DRINK in
      tea|cofee|water|all) 
         echo "Go to canteen"
         ;;
      juice|appe)
         echo "Available at home"
      ;;
      none) 
         break 
      ;;
      *) echo "ERROR: Invalid selection" 
      ;;
   esac
done
```